# Designing complex cmos circuits

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, logic-gates

I'm currently trying to understand designing complex cmos circuits for logical expressions. I came across many examples but all of them feature expressions, which are negated: $$f=\overline { A+(BC) } $$ or the whole expression has no negation parts: $$f=A+BC$$
For both cases I know how to design these circuits but I couldn't find any examples with negation parts and non negation parts, like: $$f=A+\overline { B } C$$

Is it possible to design such a circuit with cmos and if so how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is very straightforward: use an inverter to generate \$\overline{B}\$ from input \$B\$.

Moreover, CMOS logic is inherently negative, therefore, I would advice using De Morgan to make your life easier and just insert an invert at the output node.

$$ \overline{F} = \overline{A+\overline{B}C}$$

The solution below uses 10 transistors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge to negate an input of a gate you simply add an inverter on the input of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am completely redoing my answer now that I know that you know about logic gates and CMOS design. You can simply invert a "letter" and move on.

[image]

For your homework assignment, you combine all of these logic gates that you know already and just compile it into one.

[image]

Sorry for the mess and you should be able to click on the picture and zoom and see the details.

Comment: First, thank you for your time and effort. It was clear to me how to invert the whole expression. Thats why I said, that for both cases $$f=A+BC$$ and $$f=\overline { A+BC }$$ I know how to design such circuits. It is still unclear to me, how to invert jusrt a part of a expression...

Comment: You can just add a single inverter for one of your inputs.

Comment: Can you show it to me for my example above? This isn't homework...

Comment: Allow me to edit my answer... give me a sec.

Comment: @ofr13 There we go... Sorry it took so long. I kept messing up and putting the OR gate in front of the AND gate lol :)

Comment: That certainly doesn't look like a CMOS Complex Gate, but a bunch of gates connected together.